# nginx proxy_cache key hash change on each another browser request

Tags: caching, nginx

I was create config of nginx like:

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx/static levels=1:2 keys_zone=static_zone:10m inactive=10d use_temp_path$
proxy_cache_key "$request_uri$args";

location ~* \.(css|gif|ico|jpe?g|js(on)?|png|svg|webp|ttf|woff|woff2|txt|map)$ {
            proxy_hide_header Date;
            proxy_cache_revalidate on;
            proxy_pass http://static:8080;
            proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_nocache $arg_nocache;
            proxy_ignore_headers "Cache-Control" "Expires" "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";
            proxy_buffering on;
            proxy_cache static_zone;

            proxy_cache_valid 200 301 302 30m;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 10m;
            #expires max;
            add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

            access_log      off;
            add_header      Cache-Control   "public";
            add_header      Pragma          "public";
            expires         30d;
            log_not_found   off;
            tcp_nodelay     off;
}
```

On first request from Chrome all work as excepted x-proxy-cache:MISS other request got from disk cache with header x-proxy-cache:HIT. After refresh it's also HIT. But when I open page from other browsers(Opera,Edge) on this machine this request is MISS. In file system nginx create two files with different md5sum hash on a same content. For example filename 438476ac40665c852d3acde1acf769f1 head:

```
^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@/^V
W^@^@^@^@��^CW^@^@^@^@'^O
W^@^@^@^@m�,�^@^@�^@�^A^N"5703e3a7-67e"^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@$
KEY: /js/catalog.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 15:07:19 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 1662
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 16:11:19 GMT
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "5703e3a7-67e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

The second filename a6f57423c2220fba3ada5f516f6dd91c with a same content and this head:

```
^C^@^@^@^@^@^@^@        ^V
W^@^@^@^@��^CW^@^@^@^@^A^O
W^@^@^@^@m�,�^@^@�^@�^A^N"5703e3a7-67e"^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@$
KEY: /js/catalog.js
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 12 Apr 2016 15:06:41 GMT
Content-Type: application/javascript
Content-Length: 1662
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Apr 2016 16:11:19 GMT
Connection: close
Vary: Accept-Encoding
ETag: "5703e3a7-67e"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

By documentation the name of file must be md5 from key, and there is **echo -n '/js/catalog.js'| md5sum** is a6f57423c2220fba3ada5f516f6dd91c as name of one of files (it was first request). I don't want to cache in server js|css per each user|browser. Just cache it once and receive from cache to all users requests. P.S. My site use https, http2, version of nginx 1.9.14.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the *Vary: Accept-Encoding* header that's there, I would guess that Edge and Opera send different "Accept-Encoding" headers for the request. For example, one may simply send "gzip" while the other sends "gzip, deflate". Those are technically different Accept-Encoding *request* headers.

If you know that the origin won't send meaningfully different encodings that won't work between browsers you can add:

```
proxy_ignore_headers Vary;
```

You already have the proxy_ignore_headers, so you can probably just add to that.

Since all major browsers support gzip, the risk is likely very low. However, "webp" is also done via the Accept-Encoding, so that could create surprising results for some images if the origin can handle webp.

Comment: may i disable  "Accept-Encoding" headers for cache key, or some of them?

Comment: Updated my comment

Answer (score 2):

TLDR:  Request Header `Accept-Encoding` matters.

---

Consider its normal value :  `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br`.

When you change it to `Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lolkek` then Nginx will store cached response in different file. And those 2 files ( under /var/cache/nginx/) will be of the same content but with different names.

The same issue: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/1840